# Como atualizar uma variavel na tela no React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tenho minha sequinte pagina:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ArticlesScreen extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       teste: 'Teste'
     };
   }

  funcao () {
    this.state.teste = 'blabla';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
        { this.state.teste }
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={ () => this.funcao()}
          title="Press Me"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Essa função irá mostrar na tela a palavra `Teste` seguida de um botão roxo. Quando eu clico no botão o valor da variavel teste é mudado para 'blabla' e eu sei disso porque mandei printar no console.

Mas na tela não está atualizando, O nome `Teste` ainda está aparecendo na tela e não está sendo subistituido por `blabla`. Como faço para atualizar este campo em especifico, sem precisar recarregar toda a pagina?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para alterar o estado no `React` é usado o `setState` que irá evoluir o estado atual para um novo estado, então no lugar de `this.state.teste = 'blabla'` deve-se usar `this.setState({teste: 'blabla'})`. Até esse ponto o seu código ficaria assim:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ArticlesScreen extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       teste: 'Teste'
     };
   }

  funcao () {
    this.setState({
        teste : 'blabla'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
        { this.state.teste }
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={ () => this.funcao()}
          title="Press Me"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Só que isso irá causar outro problema. Dentro da `funcao` o `this` não se referencia mais à `classe` atual, mas sim à quem fez a chamada da `função`, logo o `this.setState` irá acusar um erro, já que o botão não tem referência para `setState`. Nesse caso deve-se fazer um `bind` no `construtor` para dizer que o `this` dentro de `funcao` ainda irá fazer referência à `classe`. Segue o código com as alterações:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ArticlesScreen extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       teste: 'Teste'
     };
    this.funcao = this.funcao.bind(this)
   }

  funcao () {
    this.setState({
        teste : 'blabla'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
        { this.state.teste }
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={ () => this.funcao()}
          title="Press Me"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Com essas alterações seu objetivo será alcançado. [Nesse link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hl2txk) tem um exemplo funcional com React.

Comment: Eu fiz sem o bind, e não deu erro. Mas eu entendi a função do bind.